# Returning new object array with sum of each object value using reduce

Tags: javascript

I have this array of objects:

```
let foo = [
    {
        num: 1,
        value: 0.5
    },
    {
        num: 1,
        value: 1.5
    },
    {
        num: 2,
        value: 0.5
    },
]
```

How can I reduce this array to return:

```
let bar = [
    {
        num: 1,
        value: 2, //  1.5 + 0.5
    },
    {
        num: 2,
        value: 0.5
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `findIndex` to get the object where num is same

```js
let foo = [{
    num: 1,
    value: 0.5
  },
  {
    num: 1,
    value: 1.5
  },
  {
    num: 2,
    value: 0.5
  },
];

let newData = foo.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  let findNumIndex = acc.findIndex(elem => elem.num === curr.num);
  if (findNumIndex !== -1) {
    acc[findNumIndex].value += curr.value;
  } else {
    acc.push({...curr})
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(newData)
```

Comment: This will work for the current set of data, but once the dataset grows that could be an exponential growth

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) as follows:

```js
let foo = [
    {
        num: 1,
        value: 0.5
    },
    {
        num: 1,
        value: 1.5
    },
    {
        num: 2,
        value: 0.5
    },
];

var helper = {};
let arr = foo.reduce(function(r, o) {
  var key = o.num;
  if(!helper[key]) {
    helper[key] = Object.assign({}, o);
    r.push(helper[key]);
  } else {
    helper[key].value += o.value;
  }
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [reduce](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp) & [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) like below you can get desired result. Explanation is added as comment in code.

**Note** I used `Object.assign` as `a.push(Object.assign({}, x));` instead of `a.push(x);` because with `a.push(x);` later when we update `value` while finding existing object it will also update `value` of `foo`. Using `Object.assign({}, x);` this will not happen.

```js
let foo = [{
    num: 1,
    value: 0.5
  },
  {
    num: 1,
    value: 1.5
  },
  {
    num: 2,
    value: 0.5
  },
];

// use reduce to iterate over array and produce result
var bar = foo.reduce((a, x) => {
  // find matching object from a.
  let obj = a.filter(y => y.num == x.num)[0];
  // if not exists then create new object and add into a
  // else add value to obj.value
  if (!obj) {
    a.push(Object.assign({}, x));
  } else {
    obj.value += x.value;
  }
  // return a
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply sum all the values together in an object, and then afterwards reconstruct the required data

```js
let foo = [
    {
        num: 1,
        value: 0.5
    },
    {
        num: 1,
        value: 1.5
    },
    {
        num: 2,
        value: 0.5
    },
];

// sum all values first
const summedMap = foo.reduce( (agg, cur) => (agg[cur.num] = (agg[cur.num] || 0) + cur.value, agg), {});
// reconstruct afterwards
console.log( Object.entries( summedMap ).map( ([num,value]) => ({ num: parseInt(num), value: value }) ) );
```